# Did Ben Affleck's character see Rebecca Hall's character when she activated the alarm?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-town

It all happens in the beginning of *The Town*. Did Ben Affleck's character see Rebecca Hall's character when she activated the alarm? If he did see her, did he not act because he liked her then and there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scene start where Ben was looking at Rebecca's face. Then someone knocks bank door and everyone's attention goes there including Ben. Rebecca take this opportunity and ring the alarm with her feet. I don't think anyone see her activating alarm. But we can say Ben liked her there.

Comment: Yes. You are probably right but what made me ask this is that camera shows him looking at her  right when she hits the alarm sort of telling that he caught her. Camera further on stays on him a few seconds what I interpreted as him thinking what to do because he likes her but doesn't want to mess up with the robbery.